# dispatch_once() if call on Multiple Separate Threads

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have doubts regarding `dispatch_once()` if it is calls on multiple thread. Please explain me.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask for why that's bad). Are you having a particular problem with `dispatch_once()` that you need help with, or some existing code that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it dispatches only once.

[Read the Docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_once.3.html)

If you have any actual evidence to make you doubt this please share, because almost everyone uses it to create there singletons because it never executes more than once.

Comment: You can have the situation when it called more then one time! I had this situation, when i called it from a test case and from the app delegate (in function [-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation]). In this case i had two different instances.

Comment: I had a nasty bug once: although I used static for the token, I declared the static inside the body of two different methods that called dispatch_once. In essence, I had two statics in the same file with the same name!